# PhpStorm Laravel trying to connect to MySQL database throws java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: mysql, php, database, laravel

I am trying to set up a `laravel` project in `phpstorm` but fail at connecting to a `mysql` database. These are the steps I've taken so far:

1. download and install `composer`, `vagrant` and `virtualbox`
2. create `laravel/laravel` project with `composer` (create `composer` project in `phpstorm`)
3. integrate `laravel/homestead` with `composer`: `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`
4. build homestead in `root dir`: `vendor\\bin\\homestead make` (windows)
5. personalize my local domain by setting it in `Homestead.yaml -> sites -> map`: `mydomain.com`
6. integrated the domain in `c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`: `192.168.10.10 mydomain.com`
7. create empty `ssh key` for `vagrant` to run: `fsutil file createnew C:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa 0`
8. start `VM` with `vagrant`: `vagrant up`

So far so good, everything seems to work. And here comes the problem:

9. create `mysql` database with `phpstorm's` integrated database tool, using `.env` as reference (`DB_CONNECTION=mysql`, `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`, `DB_PORT=3306`, `DB_DATABASE=laravel`, `DB_USERNAME=root`, `DB_PASSWORD=devpw`)

After installing `drivers` when trying to test connect:

```
[08S01]
    Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Or in the log:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
```

I've been trying to find a fix for some time now without success. [This Thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally) seems to provide solutions, many of which I am not sure how to implement, since they are not directed at `phpstorm`. I feel a bit overwhelmed by the whole `backend` thing and how to set it up right in `laravel`.

Am I supposed to install `mysql` on windows before integrating it into `phpstorm`?

Comment: Are you really trying to talk to a MySQL server that doesn't exist?!

Comment: It does look like it. Thanks 